# How can I get Civi CRM to display the currency in reports and so on

Tags: civicontribute

We have an organisation that can accept money from all around the world. It's usually cash or cheque when that happens. We can record the currency type in the contribution form when entering values. And also on import.

But it's almost impossible to then see what currency a value actually is.

It doesn't show in any of the reports. In fact, when I try to create a custom report, it's not even available as a field to select.

The only way I've found to see it is to drill down to the full details of the contribution, which is really slow and in-efficient.

Can I add it back somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh it's defintively available in a report - let me get to my desk and show you an example;

Install: Extended Report Extension: 
Got to your Adminster -> System -> Settings -> Manage Extensions -> Add New -> ExtendedReport (nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport)

After you've installed it -> go Administer -> CiviReport -> Create New Report from Template and select e.g. Extended Report - Contributions with Price Set data

Voila - there is your Currency -> I've checked it to show you where it lives:

[image]

Comment: Shoot I forgot! Hold on - give me a few min

Comment: Ok please see above!

Comment: Cool! Thank you.